# NoClassDefFoundError on HTC Sense

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

When debugging my app on HTC Sense, I have got (I believe it is) an exception for the following
NoClassDefFoundError on android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

The piece of code, where it seems to break is when calling this line of code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayResponse<Grid> response = (ArrayResponse<Grid>) HttpHandler.getHttpHandler().processGet(url, ArrayResponse.class, listType);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your HTC sense is running android API Version < 11 (HONEYCOMB), [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) is not yet available.

Comment: In other words, prior to API Level 11, you could perform a networking operation on your UI thread without an exception being thrown (though it still wasn't a good idea).  What I don't get is why the poster is getting the NoClassDefFoundError, though--is there an attempt to catch a NetworkOnMainThreadException somewhere, or is that class otherwise being invoked somehow?