# Android HTC Sense - Http Request/ Response exception

Tags: android

Working on the emulator, but when I am trying on an HTC Sense, i have got an exception on the last line of this code

```
url = new URL(urlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                "application/json; charset=utf-8");

//Send request
Gson requestGson = new Gson();          
OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream();
```

The exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Does not support output for the connection.getOutputStream();

I am testing on API 10, Gingerbread on an HTC Sense (remote debugging).

anyone has encountered this problem before?

Thanks.
David.

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: What are the android version you use

Comment: Are you still having [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962645/noclassdeffounderror-on-htc-sense)? Or is that part of this question? Or...?

Comment: Updated description... still having the problem I am afraid!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `setDoOutput(true)`.  It is needed for POST requests.  The first part of your code would change to look like this:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
            "application/json; charset=utf-8");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2aEYpsZEMvs

See also this other StackOverflow answer: [What exactly does URLConnection.setDoOutput() affect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587913/what-exactly-does-urlconnection-setdooutput-affect)